# How to instantiate multiple classes in one class: Python OOP

Tags: python, class, oop, object, self

I've written a code with 3 different classes - those classes initializes functions and connected between each other (class B calls function a_calc() from A class; class C calls function b_calc() from B class). I want to create Calculator() function that instantiates all of those classes (A, B, C), uses class functions in one line of code, and returns the result of execution (to be able to execute the program creating only one object Main). Here the snippet of code (simplified):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

    def a_calc(self):
        a = self.a + 1
        return a

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, A):
        self.A = A

    def b_calc(self):
        b = self.A.a_calc() + 2
        return b

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, B):
        self.B = B

    def c_calc(self):
        c = self.B().b_calc + 3
        return c

class Calculator(A, B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        result = A.a_calc() + B.b_calc() + C.c_calc()
        print(result)


calc = Calculator()
```

Yet, I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/taras/PycharmProjects/ResSysPymage/test#2.py", line 31, in <module>
    calc = Calculator()
  File "/home/taras/PycharmProjects/ResSysPymage/test#2.py", line 27, in __init__
    result = A.a_calc() + B.b_calc() + C.c_calc()
TypeError: a_calc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

How can I make my idea come true? I'd be grateful for ideas:)

Comment: Your error line is trying to call the calc method as a class method and not as the member method that it is (member methods get passed an instance of the class to work on in the self parameter)   You have an answer below that appears to be more what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing classes, instances of classes and composition vs. multiple inheritance.

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

    def a_calc(self):
        a = self.a + 1
        return a

class B:
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        self.a = a

    def b_calc(self):
        b = self.a.a_calc() + 2
        return b

class C:
    def __init__(self, b: B):
        self.b = b

    def c_calc(self):
        c = self.b.b_calc() + 3
        return c

def calculator():
    a = A()
    b = B(a)
    c = C(b)
    return a.a_calc() + b.b_calc() + c.c_calc()

print(calculator())
```